# My component is not updated when I am using Redux as a state manager?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is just a sample code I am trying to control my controlled inputs using Redux, I add the Redux to my React project and add my reducer and action but everything works well except updating my component in one of my actions.
the following code is my Reducer:

```
import actionTypes from "./actions";
const uniqid = require("uniqid");
const firstID = uniqid();
const initialState = {
  cons: [
    {
      value: "",
      id: firstID,
      added: false
    }
  ],
  pros: [
    {
      value: "",
      id: firstID,
      added: false
    }
  ],
  num: 0
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const newState = { ...state };
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.HANDLEINPUTCHANGE:
      // const newState = state;
      const changingItem = newState[action.case].find(item => {
        return item.id === action.id;
      });
      const changingItemIndex = newState[action.case].findIndex(item => {
        return item.id === action.id;
      });
      changingItem.value = action.event;
      if (
        changingItemIndex === newState[action.case].length - 1 &&
        !changingItem.added
      ) {
        alert(123);
        const newItem = {
          id: uniqid(),
          value: "",
          added: false
        };
        newState[action.case].push(newItem);
        changingItem.added = true;
        console.log(newState);
      }
      newState[action.case][changingItemIndex] = changingItem;
      return newState;
    case actionTypes.CLICK:
      newState.num += 1;
      return {
        ...newState
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

and the following code is my component, unfortunately, the HANDLEINPUTCHANGE action type did not update my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FormElement from "../../base/components/formElement/FormElement";
import actionTypes from "../../base/store/actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./style.scss";
class FormGenerator extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <ul className="row formGeneratorContainer fdiColumn">
        <li onClick={this.props.click}>{this.props.num}</li>
        {this.props[this.props.case].map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li className="row formGeneratorItem" key={index}>
              <div className="bullet d_flex jcCenter aiCenter">1</div>
              {/* <FormElement onChange={(e,index,type,)}/> */}
              <input
                name={item.id}
                type="text"
                onChange={event =>
                  this.props.onFieldValueChange(
                    event.target.value,
                    index,
                    this.props.case,
                    item.id
                  )
                }
              />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    cons: state.cons,
    pros: state.pros,
    num: state.num
  };
};
const mapDispachToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onFieldValueChange: (event, index, c, id) =>
      dispatch({
        event: event,
        index: index,
        case: c,
        id: id,
        type: actionTypes.HANDLEINPUTCHANGE
      }),
    click: () => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.CLICK })
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispachToProps
)(FormGenerator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `value` of your controlled component:

```js
<input
    name={item.id}
    type="text"
    value={item.value}
    onChange={event =>
        this.props.onFieldValueChange(
            event.target.value,
            index,
            this.props.case,
            item.id
        )
    }
/>
```

Other problems are in your reducer, you are mutating the redux state with these lines:

```js
newState[action.case].push(newItem);
// ...
newState[action.case][changingItemIndex] = changingItem;
```

Look at these sections in the redux documentation:

- [Inserting and Removing Items in Arrays](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays)
- [Updating an Item in an Array](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array)

Comment: @mrtea in addition to my answer, do you really want to set value of new item to empty string in yiour reducer. Your value in `action.event` is lost in such case.

Comment: @lavor-I see, but the problem was that when I add the value attribute to my input, it changes to a read-only field

Comment: I believe in what you are saying but another problem is that my initial state is updated without value attribute but the UI did not update

Comment: It is not readonly, it is controlled, you probably do not perform state update in reducer or mapping state to props correctly, so the value is still empty. Try to debug the mapStateToProps function and check if the state is changed after you perform the state change.